# What does it mean "Do not mistake my silence for a lack of grief"

Tags: american-english

I tried hard to fond the meaning of this quotation but failed. Can somebody described it? Quote doesn't make sense to me

Comment: The speaker is explaining that his/her way of expressing grief is quiet.

Comment: If you think my silence is because I am not grieving, you would be wrong.  Don’t make that mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that the speaker may be grieving, but they are not expressing that grief out loud by, say, crying or ranting. It is an example of what we British call "keeping a stiff upper lip" in other words not letting your lip tremble in order to prevent breaking into tears.